# pkg-config indicates libxml2 not found

Tags: pkg-config, libxml

I've installed libxml2-dev in my Ubuntu 20.04 terminal (under WSL), as it's a requirement for [pgModeler](https://pgmodeler.io/support/installation).  I used `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` and it seemed to install ok. The pgModeler instruction includes "To check if the library is correctly installed" run this command: `pkg-config libxml­2.0 --cflags --libs`
For me, this gives:

> ```
> Package libxml2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. 
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'libxml2.0.pc'
> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable 
> No package 'libxml2.0' found
> ```

Answers to some questions suggest adding the path to PKG_CONFIG_PATH. To determine what path to check, I installed locate (`sudo apt install mlocate`) and using `locate libxml | grep '\.pc'`, I found that this file exists:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc

Then running `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` gives (my highlighting):

> /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:**/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig**:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig

which indicates to me that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` is already in the default path for `pkg-config`.

So, why would I get "No package 'libxml2.0' found", and how might I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same command after rebooting your pc ?

Comment: Yes, just retried it, same result.

Comment: The command should probably have been `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml-2.0` or perhaps better `pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0`. Note the hyphen.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks - that answers my original question.  I've corrected -libs to --libs (initial error from copying and pasting via MS Word).  Could you please promote your comment as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 7):

You have to ignore the suggestion from pgModeler [documentation](https://pgmodeler.io/support/installation#linuxReq).

Correct name of the libxml2 configuration file for pkg-config is *libxml-2.0.pc*, you have already installed it from [`libxml2-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libxml2-dev/filelist).

Simply proceed with the compilation:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libxml2-dev qt5-default libpqxx-dev libpq-dev libqt5svg5-dev qttools5-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler.git -b master
cd pgmodeler
git clone https://github.com/pgmodeler/plugins -b master
qmake PREFIX+=/usr/local -r pgmodeler.pro
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Also you should know that pgModeler 0.9.2 is packaged in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/pgmodeler, so it installable as simple as

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgmodeler
```

Comment: @ N0rbert - that's really useful information and is helping me progress, thanks.  I'm hitting other issues now, will post a separate question if I can't work round these.